# Getting specific keys from dictionaries

Tags: python-3.x, api, dictionary, flask

I am developing an API service for my website. The website is about Recipes, where a user is supposed to register on his first visit, then log in. When he logs in he gets an access token, which he uses to do REST services on categories and recipes.

So coming to Recipes, he can give a title, ingredients, and directions. Example:

```
     {
        "title" : "api recipe",
        "directions" : "Testing api recipe directions",
        "ingredient1" : "postman",
        "ingredient2" : "ing2",
        "ingredient3" : "me",
        "ingredient4" : "ingredient4",
        "ingredient5" : "ingredient5"
     }
```

Now, I am facing a problem when it comes to PUT method. I want to enable a user to edit a recipe giving only that which he wants to edit. Example:

```
    {
        "title" : "PUT"
    }
```

Using PUT method, if a user provides an ingredient as such:

```
    {
        "ingredient2" : "Potatoes",
        "ingredient5" : "stackexchange"
    }
```

I would like to only change the ingredients that he provided me with and leave the rest the way it is.

Before coming to my question, when a user provides the above, I get a dictionary with the keys and values he/she has provided. My question is, how can I get all the ingredients he wants to edit plus their number?

my code:

```
        data = request.get_json()

        category = Category.query.filter_by(user_id=user_id).filter_by(id=category_id).first()

        if not category:
            return jsonify({'message' : 'category does not exists'})

        category.edit_recipe(data, id=recipe_id)

        return jsonify({'message' : 'Edited successfully'})

def edit_recipe(self, data, *args, **kwargs):
    edit_this = None
    if 'id' in kwargs:
        edit_this = Recipe.query.filter_by(id=kwargs['id']).filter_by(category_id=self.id).first()
    else:
        edit_this = Recipe.query.filter_by(title=kwargs['prev_title']).filter_by(category_id=self.id).first()

    """TODO: Get ingredient from data followed by its number.
       if data == {'title' = 'change title', 'ingredient2' = 'change ing 2', 'ingredient5' = 'change ing 5'}
       then I want to get keys that start with ingredient followed by their number and its value
    """

    if 'title' in data:
        edit_this.title = data['title']

    if 'directions' in data:
        edit_this.directions = data['directions']

    if 'filename' in data:
        edit_this.filename = data['filename']

    db.session.commit()
```

Comment: Question is not clear. Where are you saving your data?

Comment: can you add the code where you see the provided data in a variable?

Comment: Okay, I have added the code and explained a bit. Hope now its clear. And sorry for not being clear the first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get only the ingredients, the following below should

keyValue = {
    "title" : "api recipe",
    "directions" : "Testing api recipe directions",
    "ingredient1" : "postman",
    "ingredient2" : "ing2",
    "ingredient3" : "me",
    "ingredient4" : "ingredient4",
    "ingredient5" : "ingredient5"
}

oldListOfKeys = keyValue.keys()

ingredientsList = filter(lambda x: x not in ["directions", "title"], oldListOfKeys)

newDict = {key: keyValue[key] for key in keyValue if key in ingredientsList}

print newDict  # {'ingredient4': 'ingredient4', 'ingredient5': 'ingredient5', 'ingredient1': 'postman', 'ingredient2': 'ing2', 'ingredient3': 'me'}

Comment: @Harith i have updated the codes, that should remove directions from it.

Answer (score 0):

(Am using this in a flask app with sqlAlchemy- hope it helps)
In your put method, first query of a specific recipe for example

`recipe = Recipe.query.filter_by(recipe_id=id).first()`

Then you can access the specific keys like this

`data = request.get_json()`

`recipe.title = data['title']`

`recipe.directions = data['directions']`

`recipe.ingredient1 = data['ingredient1']`

`recipe.ingredient2 = data['ingredient2']`

Comment: yes, but I don't know how many ingredients the user has provided, and the number of the ingredient the user wants to edit. Sorry for being unclear

Comment: Oooh, that now now tricky on my side. thought the user is only allowed to edit, didn't consider adding. How do your models look like